# ELB routes to server hostname

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have setup ELB on the AWS console and registered a node on that where I have installed a tool . As soon as I access the ELB , it reroutes to the server hostname and starts showing that in the URL instead of the ELB endpoint. What may be causing this behavior? PFA the setting of the ELB:
[image]

Comment: ELB does not do this.  Your web server is doing this.

Answer (score 0):

ELB will only manage routing traffic to instances behind it. The change in URL may be due to the configuration of your tool. Let me know the tool you installed and web server running on it to help you better.

Comment: Thanks , I have installed Chef private supermarket tool on the box , it is running nginx , let me know which config should I focus on.